# PHP Fatal error: Declaration of Zend\\Stdlib\\ArrayObject::offsetGet()

Tags: zend-framework2, apache2, centos6, arrayobject

Since i install ZF2 (2.3.1) into my centos server i've got this error.

PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject::offsetGet()

CentOS6
apache2
PHP5.3.3
mysql5.5

what i need to do to get rid of it? 
anyone help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zend Framework 2.3 requires **PHP 5.3.23** or above. You'll need to update PHP to fix this error. Alternatively, if you can't upgrade for whatever reason, downgrade to the latest 2.2.x version of ZF instead, which should work with older versions of PHP 5.3.x.

Comment: i thought my PHP5.3.3 should be ok ? but anyway i'll give a try on downgrade ZF to 2.2.0 instead 

thank you

Comment: The min PHP version was changed in ZF 2.3 because of some bugs. Some details in the release announcement: http://framework.zend.com/blog/zend-framework-2-3-0-released.html